# getting 'failed to copy directory: invalid symlink' in docker .NET Core container

Tags: docker, .net-core

I'm trying to build a docker image using .NET Core. In my Dockerfile, an error occurs when it copies files from the container host to the container. My application is divided into two main folders, one for the Angular frontend and one for the .NET Core backend. There is a symlink in the backend to the frontend using .NET Core's SPA.

It's set up like this:

- app root/

  - Web folder (frontend)
  - API folder (backend)/

    - ClientApp (symlink to frontend)

During the build process, when the Dockerfile code gets to this line:

```
COPY ./API/. /app/API
```

It throws this error:

> ERROR: Service 'portal' failed to build: failed to copy files: failed
>   to copy directory: invalid symlink
>   "\\?\Volume{45afd2d1-b8ce-4ce7-9ec2-f39bcad96f75}\app\API\ClientApp"
>   -> "..\Web"

I verified that the file structure in the docker container is the same as in the container host. I'm using Windows mode in docker. I didn't get this error when I was in Linux mode in docker. I'm not sure if this is a Windows or a Docker problem. Does anyone have a solution?

UPDATE: For some more background, The SPA Root in the .NET Core backend is set to this `<SpaRoot>..\Web\</SpaRoot>`

I'm guessing I need to modify this path. I found this [Docker forum post](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-file-copy-fails/55140/2) that could be related. I don't want to modify the path where it works in Docker but doesn't work anywhere else.

UPDATE 2: I tried recreating the symlink in the dockerfile.

I ran the following:

```
RUN mklink /j app/API/ClientApp /app/Web
```

I received 'Invalid switch - "API"' error.

Comment: Not a solution, but I've found symlinks on the host and docker are very finicky (windows symlinks behave different than MacOS, for example).  Is it possible to change your app to avoid the need for a symlink?  You may save a lot of headaches and solutions that work in one OS but don't in another.

Comment: @Matthew Unfortunately, that is not possible. It's a work app and we need the symlink for some custom authentication.